# Get Notified of popViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I need to save my data by calling a method I already have when a viewController is popped using the back button created by the UINavigationController.

Is there a way to get a delegate callback or a notification I didn't see anything in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be notified that the view will be disappearing, with the view controller method viewWillDisappear:, however, this will be called each time the view is moved offscreen, whether that means the controller is popped or a new controller is pushed, or whatever else may cause your view to disappear.

Perhaps a better design would be to save your data in your controllers dealloc method. Normally, a navigation controller is the owner of a view pushed into it's stack, so popping it usually causes it to deallocate. This isn't always the case though and depends on how you've written your app.

Comment: Wow, I should have figured that one out. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In your viewWillDisappear method, you can check the property:

```
[self isMovingFromParentViewController]
```

to find out [if the view is disappearing as a result of being popped](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingFromParentViewController) off the stack or not.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, better than other solutions. Quite helpful answer and information! Thanks @Anthony C