# iOS navigationcontroller get which viewcontroller got popped

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my app i use UINavigationController for navigating between viewcontrollers.
Whenever the user navigates back to the main viewcontroller i want to see which viewcontroller got popped.

Is there a way to determine this from the main viewcontroller?

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,

Zoli

Comment: please use the search facility, in 5 seconds I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834723/get-notified-of-popviewcontroller?rq=1

Comment: i will apologize as soon as you tell me how viewvillappear will tell me which viewcontroller got popped. since it has no parameters, it's NOT a solution.

Comment: Using viewWillDisappear IS a solution. The rest of the solution will depend upon your app structure, but I would use an NSNotification personally inside viewWillDisappear.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you have to place your own custom button instead of using navigationcontroller default back button. And try the following code in the selector of that custom button.

NSLog(@"><><><%@", NSStringFromClass([[self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject] class]));

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I ended up creating a delegate for the child viewcontroller that calls a selector of the parent viewcontroller before it gets popped. It's not nice, but working. I'm sure there's a more elegant way for that